# string<char> vs string <unsigned char>

Tags: c++, string, performance

I have a question concerning the difference between a "normal" C++ string and a string of  unsigned characters.
When generating some pseudorandom strings of chars and of `unsigned char`s, I noticed a huge performance difference between the time the code would need to build a normal string and one composed of `unsigned char`s.

The code I used:

```
#include <tr1/random>
#include <string>


using namespace std;
using namespace tr1;

typedef basic_string<unsigned char > ustring;

string generateString(){
    string retStr;
    char a;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){             
        a = rand();
        retStr+=a;            
    }
    return retStr;
}

ustring generateUString(){
    ustring retStr;
    unsigned char a;

    for(unsigned int i = 0; i < 1000; i++){
        a = rand();
        retStr+=a;
    }
    return retStr;
}


int main(int argc, char* args[]){

    srand(0);

    string thing;
    ustring uthing;

    for(unsigned int i = 1; i< 100000; i++){ 
        //thing = generateString(); // this needs 2 second to execute
        uthing = generateUString(); //  and this 13

    }

    return 0;
}
```

So basically, the code needs 2 seconds to execute `generateString()` 100 000 times, while it needs 13 seconds to execute `generateUString()` 100 000 times.

What exactly is the reason for this? I guess it's the `+=` operator, since the difference melted away when I cut the corresponding lines (actually, `generateUstring()` seems to be faster then, I guess because the modulo arithmetic is easier in that case).

But why then is it so much faster to append a char to a string than to append a `unsigned char` to a string of `unsigned char`s? And should I hence avoid strings of `unsigned char`s?

Comment: Compiler, flags, system...? FWIW, both are roughly equally fast on on GCC 4.3.4: [`char`](http://ideone.com/0a7Ci) and [`unsigned char`](http://ideone.com/f0bGC).

Comment: Compiler gcc 4.4.3.,flags none, system Ubuntu, 64 bit.

Comment: `flags none` ??? You have no optimizations enabled?

Comment: Oh gosh, I guess that was the difference, yes. I wouldn't have thought that it could make that much of a difference for such a simple code, but I guess I know better now.

Comment: @john_leo: usually, the simpler the code, the more difference the optimizations make.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is probably that `basic_string<char>` is explicitly instantiated in `libstdc++.so` which (by default) is compiled with `-O2`. So if you don't compile your program with optimization the  `basic_string<unsigned char>` operations will be un-optimized, but all the `basic_string<char>` operations that aren't inlined will use the optimized code in `libstdc++.so`.